# Do you know some good resources for learning NoSQL databases?

Tags: database, nosql

I consider to use some NoSQL database in one of my project. **Do you know some good starting points for a newbie in this topic?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick your particular "NoSQL" database first -- or at least *type* of "NoSQL" -- I'm going with the assumption that there *is* a reason why you want "NoSQL". Do you need object graph traversal? Explicit distributed clustering? Fast write/append? Dumb key/value associations? The selection should be based off more than a "I want something NoSQL" as different approaches can offer significant advantages (along with significant drawbacks) :-)

And, as often, google/wikipedia are a good place to start:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Answer (score 2):

http://nosql-database.org/ has a long list of alternative databases, grouped in categories by type of technology.  It has links to each product's website, lists of books, and forums, news, etc. about NoSQL.

Also see http://nosqlsummer.org/city/krakow.  This is the Kraków chapter of a reading club for studying NoSQL concepts.  I see from your profile that you live in Kraków.

Comment: Thanks:) In fact I live in Kraków so this is a bull's eye:)