# New to NoSQL and Mongodb - Good guide for learning?

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

So a similar question was asked here:

[Do you know some good resources for learning NoSQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172107/do-you-know-some-good-resources-for-learning-nosql-databases)

but the answer the asker got was basically "pick an actual db and then learn that".

I am using mongo, and getting by O.K. but I remember seeing a great mapping between standard SQL queries and their mongo equivalents somewhere. Now, despite tons of googling I can't find that chart again.

Does anyone know a good resource for an experienced user of SQL to understand Mongo equivalents to basic queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the chart you are looking for is this:
http://rickosborne.org/download/SQL-to-MongoDB.pdf

Other than that, the [MongoDB.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) documentation is a good starting point. There's also the [MongoDB Cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/) - not much there, but a few scenarios. More something to keep an eye on as stuff is added.

I recently bought [MongoDB: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920001096) book from O'Reilly - the best single resource I've read so far, so I really recommend that.

Comment: Just for the record, you can read that book at [google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=BQS33CxGid4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=MongoDB:+The+Definitive+Guide&hl=en&ei=mYBhTeyoNJHV4gbWvfXLCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) too. (But it's worth to buy it!)

Comment: I feel the path to understanding starts from the overview (the bigger picture) of the subject and then strategically focusing down to individual pillars of fundamental concepts. So I would recommend to start at Glossary of MongoDB which will give you a fuller picture of its capabilities. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-init-script

Answer (score 0):

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/392418792/translate-sql-to-mongodb-mapreduce
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart

Answer (score 0):

The [community page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Community) at MongoDB.org has a bunch of great leads for you, including the IRC channel (those guys are always online ready to answer any questions you have for free), the Google Groups, and perhaps the most important link they have on there is links to MongoDB events where you can go for a full day of presentations of MongoDB.

I went to the first MongoNYC and it was great.  Although, after the conference, most (if not all) of the presenters also presented the same content at the MongoDb NY meetups for free.

Check [Meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com/find/?keywords=mongoDB&mcId=z10011&mcName=&lat=&lon=&userFreeform=&gcResults=&op=search&resetgeo=true&events=&submitButton=Search) for local MongoDB groups.

Finally, I found that StackOverflow is a great way to learn too, just by subscribing to the mongodb tag and reading it all.